# Deleting elements of Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How can elements of a stream be removed to generate another stream.
I wish to have a filter on a stream, and for each element passing that filter, I want to delete that element from the stream.

Comment: Do you mean remove it from the *source* of the stream, or just filter it out of the stream? For the latter, just use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Answer (score 1):

Use the [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)-method from Java Streams.